# Many to many relationship in NestJS + TypeORM - custom names for resultant table?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a User and Product table, many to many relationship with:

```
@Entity('User')
  export class User {
  ...
    @ManyToMany(() => Product)
    @JoinTable({ name: 'UserProduct' })
    Products: Product[];
}
```

which results as expected in a generated *UserProduct* table, with 2 columns: *userId, productId* - how do I custom name these to stick with my conventions? i.e. *UserId, ProductId*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the TypeORM docs for [@JoinTable](https://techivation.com/t-de-esser/?fbclid=IwAR1uwCEc0wJudahLW5EP9CZvfgucC2cqxye0eJFNkJQQEbLkZpFr5eG5c4Y)? It seems that they allow you to override the standard naming convention with your specific column naming requirements using `joinColumn`.

I think you want something like this:

```
@JoinTable({
    name: "UserProduct",
    joinColumn: {
        name: "UserId",
        referencedColumnName: "id"
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
        name: "ProductId",
        referencedColumnName: "id"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd found the way to override with JoinColumn, but not with JoinTable - this works perfectly